# Locate transitive dependencies for a given namespace in a single assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, resharper

How can I locate all transitive dependencies for set of types in a given namespace?  For example, let's say I have 4 assemblies:  A, B, C, D.  Said 4 assemblies have the following references:

> A -> B 
>   B -> C 
>   C -> D

So A -> D.  Now I want to know all types "T" in namespace "NS" that are required by A.

I tried a couple techniques:

1. ReSharper: I was unable to determine **T** (types required).  I only found **D** (assemblies).
2. Delete **D**.  Build A.  Look through the errors to manually locate D.NS.T's.  Slow and error prone.

**For D.NS (assembly with given namespace) give me all T (types) required by A.**.  Concretely, "give me all Types required by A belonging to Company.Domain in assembly MyDatabaseAssembly".

How can I do this?  I'm open to other tools.  However, I already own ReSharper and visual studio pro 2013.

Comment: I'd guess NDepend can do this

Answer (score 0):

If you can list the namespaces of assembly A then [NsDepCop](http://nsdepcop.codeplex.com) can do this. Its a free open-source tool and checks whether namespace dependencies conform to your rules.

So if the namespaces of assembly A are A1, A2, etc. (with any sub-namespaces) and the namespace you don't want them to reference is Company.Domain (and any sub-namespaces) then the NsDepCop rule config would look something like this.

```
<NsDepCopConfig IsEnabled="True" CodeIssueKind="Warning">
  <Allowed From="*" To="*" />
  <Disallowed From="A1.*" To="Company.Domain.*" />
  <Disallowed From="A2.*" To="Company.Domain.*" />
  ...
</NsDepCopConfig>
```

Build the solution and all dependency violations will be reported as warnings so you can refactor till zero warning is reached.